# unix file system - boot block

Tags: unix, filesystems

In the unix file system, only one boot block is needed to boot / initialize the operating system, why do every file systems have a boot block ? and it's possibly empty.

Is there any purpose to design for this ?

Comment: In unix file system, all disks could become boot disk. This is why all disks has boot block. Boot blocks of disks are used to determine which disks are boot disk or not. Empty boot block is used to express that disk is not boot disk.

Comment: Thanks. You need put this to the answer blank instead of here so that I can choose your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In unix file system, all disks could become boot disk. This is why all disks has boot block. Boot blocks of disks are used to determine which disks are boot disk or not. Empty boot block is used to express that disk is not boot disk.